# Intellij, how to import a module in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, kotlin

I have a maven project called `assimp` and I'd like to add, temporarily, the module `glm` as dependency

I went into project property and added it through "Libraries", like shown here:

[image]

But I still have no trace (that is I can't use anything of it) of `glm` module inside `assimp`

If you look at the project window, it misses

[image]

How can I solve?

Ps: note that the `glm` module is not on maven repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look under Modules and in the right-hand pane select the tab Dependencies. There you should be able to manually add the dependency of `assimp` on `glm`. If not, then it might give you a better idea of what's wrong.